# How to Store Graph-Like Data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

This is a bit of a complex one, and even trying to think it over is somewhat confusing.

Basically I'm having to design a series of tables that will house information about many different pieces of electrical equipment. The arrangement of this equipment is quite complex, and can vary fairly drastically.

The different types of equipment are as follows:

```
RDC - Remote Distribution Center
EBD - Electrical Bus Duct
UPB - Upright Panel Board
PDU - Power Distribution Unit
```

Now the way these units work together is slightly confusing as well.

```
PDU - Powers RDC's, EBD's, and UPB's. They are often redundant, and have a secondary 
      unit that powers the same equipment in the event of a power failure.
      Can also contain breakers and power equipment directly.
RDC - Powers nearly all the equipment on the data center floors, are usually redundant.
      They have two units side by side, being powered by a PDU. In the event of a 
      failure, the second RDC is activated and resumes operations.
EBD - Nearly identical to the RDC, being phased out, but still needs to be tracked in a
      similar fashion.
UPB - Similar to an RDC, however, they are not redundant.
```

Now what I'm trying to do is figure out the most simplistic method of tracking this crazy relationship between all the different items?

I need to track the redundant sources for all possible hardware, but also what powers each unit. This can be quite complex because if two PDUs power a set of two RDCs, we need to be able to track exactly what goes where.

Any idea on exactly where to start?

**EDIT** Here is a visual representation of what I'm after. The objects that are touching are redundant, and must be documented as such. Also, the different hardware that is connected to each device must be cataloged.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Set up one table for equipment, one table for power supplies, then a third table that matches a piece of equipment with its power supply.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for an entity-relationship model. You can learn more about that here: [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

But, in the interest of answering your question, here's how I would set it up. I believe I understand the relationships between entities. My shorthand follows this pattern: Table [TableName] ([columns]). I tried to name them so they make the relationships obvious.

```
Table RDC (id)
Table PDU (id)
Table UPB (id, PduId) // Many-to-one relationship between UPBs and Pdus
Table PDU (id)
Table PDU_RDC (PduId, RdcId) // represents many-to-many relationship between PDUs and RDCs
Table PDU_EBD (PduId, EbdId) // represents many-to-many relationship between PDUs and EBDs
```

Good luck!

Comment: That's somewhat similar to what I'm after, but I'm afraid it may be a bit more complex. Here is an image of what the relationships look like: http://imgur.com/EV4k7DL.jpg

Comment: ...I see. Might you be able to accomplish the grouping constraints by introducing additional tables for PDU Clusters, RDC Clusters, etc., and then creating the relationships between the clusters instead of the entities themselves?

Comment: Or perhaps you could represent the coupled PDUs, EBDs, and RDCs by adding a column to the PDU table that is a foreign key reference to the ID of that table that is something like "PduPartnerId" (and repeating on the RDC and EBD tables)

Comment: I was thinking of maybe making a superclass table that consists of 3 columns, ID, Hardware_ID, and Hardware_Type. Then using this to build all relationships. That way I can trace everything back to the appropriate table if needed, but I also have a way to enforce all the different relationships. Not sure how well it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing on "entities" focus on basic facts. Each gives a table or view.

Some of the basic facts just involve entities; others are about (ids of) entities:

```
RDC(id) // id identifies a remote distribution center
powers(pid,rid) // PDU pid powers RDC rid
backup(rid1,rid2) // RDC rid1 is backed up by RDC rid2
active(rid) // RDC is active
```

Until you supply adequate statements you want to make/use we can only answer you with guesses or principles; give statements and business rules we can suggest alternatives and rearrangements.

When you get AND between two statements you already have, the table with that statement is expressible as a JOIN of the two statements' tables.

You can introduce notions like hardware type but the tables/statements for that way will involve simpler statements (for which you may have defined tables). The former tables/statements are joins of the latter, and the latter are projections of the former. This means you can write views of either way in terms of the other. Neither is more complex; you have fewer things with more parts or more simpler things. Queries involving given statement will be simpler--but using the appropriate view neither is more complex. However, each way has corresponding versions of constraints and SQL might make certain constraints hard to express declaratively. Investigate join performance later as a non-premature optimization.

When a column is a function of a set of columns there is an FD from the set to the column. A column set forms a key when all other columns are functions of it but of no subset. FDs and keys are kinds of constraint.

There will be certain constraints that a projection of a source table is always a subset of a projection of a target table (maybe the same one). That's an IND. Informally it means something(c1,...) IMPLIES otherthing(c1,...). Formally, EXISTS x1,... t1(c1,...,x1,...) IMPLIES EXISTS y1,... t2(c1,...,y1,...). If the target projection' columns form a key in its table, there's also a FK. SQL FK [sic] declarations actually declare INDs.

There will be other constraints.

Supplying whateever-to-whateverness for a table is just one property about it. Not being 0-or-more-to-0-or-more means a corresponding FD or IND holds. People talk about "a" "1-to-n" "relationship" between entity types or tables but that's just sloppy unclear expression of some constraint. Make sure you know exactly the table(s) and constraint(s) that means.

Read about ORM2 (or NIAM or FCO-IM) because it is based on relational principles (although could be moreso).